# JS-XLSX library error

Tags: javascript, excel

I have posted this issue to the developers of this library, but also thought I would post this in stack overflow too. So the issue goes like this:

I downloaded this Excel sheet from here and unzipped the file : http://www.contextures.com/SampleData.zip

Then I parsed the Excel file in here : http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/, by uploading it

and then viewing the output as formulae.

Particularly compare the value at cell number G2 in the Excel and the formulae output.

In the Excel sheet, its F2*E2.

In the formulae output , its G2==1,6

This causes issues when I try to import an Excel sheet into an html table

Now if I go ahead and save the cell G2 specifically in the Excel sheet and then upload the Excel sheet again to the link above, it works well, but now G3 gets affected and so on !!!!

Not sure whats causing this issue.

I am trying this out in Windows 8 environment and chrome browser.

I am currently digging into the library and found that this issue is occuring mostly because the value of variable x.f is getting messed up somehow in the method sheet_to_formulae in file xlsx.js that is causing the above issue. Note I inserted the console.log statements myself, to debug the issue, but thats pretty much it, all other code is same as in the repository.

```js
function sheet_to_formulae(sheet) {
 var cmds, y = "", x, val="";
 if(sheet == null || sheet["!ref"] == null) return "";
 var r = safe_decode_range(sheet['!ref']), rr = "", cols = [], C;
 cmds = new Array((r.e.r-r.s.r+1)*(r.e.c-r.s.c+1));
 var i = 0;
 for(C = r.s.c; C <= r.e.c; ++C) cols[C] = encode_col(C);
 for(var R = r.s.r; R <= r.e.r; ++R) {
  console.log("IN R FOR LOOP");
  rr = encode_row(R);
  for(C = r.s.c; C <= r.e.c; ++C) {
   y = cols[C] + rr;
   x = sheet[y];
   val = "";
   if(x === undefined) continue;
   if(x.f != null) val = x.f;
   else if(x.w !== undefined) val = "'" + x.w;
   else if(x.v === undefined) continue;
   else val = ""+x.v;
   console.log("X.V IS " + x.v);
   console.log("X.F IS " + x.f);
   console.log("X.W IS " + x.w);
   console.log("VAL IS " + val);
   console.log("Y IS " + y);
   cmds[i++] = y + "=" + val;
   console.log("CMDS " + cmds[i]);
  }
 }
 cmds.length = i;
 return cmds;
}
```

However, its still not very clear. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post relevant code and documentation here instead of linking to it.

Comment: Done, please have a look.